# iPhone. Open application after call

Tags: iphone, call

If the user received a call during application running, how to automatically open the application after call ended. And how to restore the last session, so that the user would not start from the beginning?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement the following methods from the UIApplicationDelegate protocol:

- *applicationWillResignActive* is called when the phone receives an incoming call
- *applicationWillTerminate* is called when the user answers the call
- *applicationDidBecomeActive* is called if the user choose not to answer the call

*applicationWillTerminate* will give a few seconds to save your apps current state. The easiest way to save state is through the NSUserDefaults class. When the app starts again you read your state from NSUserDefaults and restore the app to its previous state.

Comment: just to clarify: if user answer the call, he will have to lunch the application again? right?

Comment: If the user answers a call the application will quit and then launch automatically once the call is finished.